# If statement with logical or operator

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want my function to check to see if the status is 'closed' or 'complete' and if it is either of those to perform the action in brackets.

For some reason I can't seem to make that work, it will check closed but not check complete.

```
for (var id in games) {
if (games[id].league === 'NCAAB')
if ((games[id].status == 'complete')||(games[id].status == 'closed')) {
  sports.clearTimer();
}
    if (ts >= games[id].scheduledTimeUnix) { xxxxxx}
```

Right now the timer isn't being cleared despite the fact the only two status for the nodes are complete and closed. The XXXX represents api calls that occur and the function is constantly making those calls.

Comment: Without a [mcve] there's no way for us to know why without lots of guessing

Comment: Is the value really `complete`? Isn't it `completed`, for example?

Comment: it should work this way (beside the superfluous brackets).

Comment: Maybe because `if (games[id].league === 'NCAAB')` evaluates to `false`?

Comment: First use your debugger to see what code path is being followed and what the value of games[id].status is.  Alternatively, you could temporarily insert `console.log(games[id].status)`  Also watch for `Complete` or misspellings.  It's likely undefined.  Or maybe you have the property name wrong.  For example, maybe `.state` instead of `.status` or something like that.

Answer (score -2):

`or` check for the true, if it gets one true it will not check other condition and perform the action preceding it.

```
if ((games[id].status == 'closed')||(games[id].status == 'complete'))
```

so if you get

```
games[id].status == 'closed'
```

as true , it will not check for

```
(games[id].status == 'complete')
```

Comment: You don't answer the question. OP don't ask how `OR` works, OP has problem with `status == 'complete'` - than the timer isn't cleared for some reason.